# Get mapping between simple property and navigation property - Entity Framework 5

Tags: c#, entity-framework-5

I have an entity with below properties:

Simple Properties:

```
public int ParentLocationID {get; set;}
public int ChildLocationID {get; set;}
```

Navigation Properties:

```
public Location Location1 {get; set;}
public Location Location2 {get; set;}
```

Here, both the simple properties refer to the foreign key relationship with a Location Table. This information is available when I open the Designer.cs for the model.

But how can I know in the code that ParentLocationID is using which navigation property Location1 or Location2?

Comment: Can you post your entity class?. Also you can check this page . http://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/configuration/data-annotation-attributes/foreignkey-attribute .

Comment: @Haksu the entity class is similar to what I have mentioned with just additional simple properties. Additionally, the scenario for me is not that of IEntityCollection. Its for one to one mapping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the ForeignKey annotation?

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

public class MyModel
{
    public int ParentLocationID {get; set;}
    public int ChildLocationID {get; set;}

    [ForeignKey("ParentLocationID")]
    public Location Location1 {get; set;}
    [ForeignKey("ChildLocationID")]
    public Location Location2 {get; set;}
}
```

Is this what you mean?

Comment: I can use this as an option. Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 0):

> But how can I know in the code that ParentLocationID is using which navigation property Location1 or Location2?

You can rename the navigation properties in the EDXM Model Browser. Just right click the navigation property and rename it so instead of `Location1`, you can change it to `ParentLocation`.

This will survive if you update the model from the database any number of times. However, if you totally delete the table from the EDMX and then re-create it, you will need to rename it again (but this is rarely done).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But I don't want to go for this approach as then I will have to update the reference everywhere in the proxies as well.

Comment: What proxy are you talking about?

Comment: @Mustafa  If you are talking about the auto generated code, it will rename them all for you. This is the normal way of doing things in db first approach.

Comment: Yoshi there are client proxies for the services. But anyways, changing the property names is not an option.

Comment: I understand that, but as the edmx is much older and with many dependencies, we do not want to play around with that.

Comment: @Mustafa then just right click and see which is foreign key is for which navigation in the properties. Do not change it but you can find out from there. Maybe I am missing something...

Comment: Yoshi I want to know about that at runtime in my code. So that is a blocker.